# Como sair da JOptionPane sem fechar a janela Principal?

Tags: java, joptionpane

Estou tentando criar um programa em Java de Agenda, porém quando saio da `JOptionPane` que configura o nome do Proprietário da Agenda, chamada pela janela principal, toda a aplicação é fechada.

```
String nome = "";
do{
    nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Informe o proprietário da Agenda", "Cadastro de proprietário",WIDTH);
    if(nome == null){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(nome.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo não pode estar vazio!");
    }
    else{
        Agenda agenda = new Agenda(nome);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A agenda do "+agenda.getNome()+" foi criada com sucesso!");
    }
}while(nome.isEmpty());
```

Eu sei que o problema está no `System.exit(0)`, mas não sei como poderia resolver.

Comment: Existe algum motivação pra usar um `do while` nesse contexto ?

Comment: Apresente um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o codigo,

Comment: Essa forma está muito ruim, existe outras formas melhores e menos repetitivas que esta, mas não da pra sugerir nada melhor, sem testar. Acesse o link acima e forneça um exemplo minimo que nos permita testar seu codigo e simular o problema.

Comment: Vou melhorar o código pra facilitar

Comment: @FranciscoOliveira não se esqueça do **[mcve]**

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a escolha de um `do while` não foi a melhor nesse cenário, pois quando o `JOptionpane` for fechado, você já tem essa informação em mãos, que é o retorno do valor.

Se o objetivo é solicitar ao usuário um valor, até que ele seja válido, pode ser usado um `while`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nome = solicitarPropietario();

    while(nome == null || nome.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campo não pode estar vazio!");
        nome = solicitarPropietario();
    }

    Agenda agenda = new Agenda(nome);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A agenda do " + agenda.getNome() + " foi criada com sucesso!");
}

public static String solicitarPropietario() {
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Informe o proprietário da Agenda", "Cadastro de proprietário");
}
```

Comment: Apesar de válida, soluções baseada nesse monte de joptionpane são terriveis. Isso polui demais a aplicação.